# Formula returning multiple non-adjacent columns from an array

Tags: arrays, excel

`=INDEX(example_array, , column_num)` returns a column from `example_array`

What if I wanted an array formula like:
`=INDEX(example_array, , {1,3,7})` to return an array of the non-adjacent columns #1, #3 and #7 from `example_array`?

Is this possible with standard excel formulas or do I need to use VBA?

Answer (score 5):

Try this formula

`=INDEX(example_array,N(IF(1,{1,3,7})))`

This follows one of the methods suggested by **XOR LX** [here](http://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/#more-98)

Comment: indeed, and just to add the same technique can be used for returning selected columns: `=INDEX(example_array,N(IF(1,ROW(example_array)-MIN(ROW(example_array))+1)),N(IF(1,{1,3,7})))`